# Google Maps API - Marker

Tags: google-maps, marker

I need to use the google map API on my Website and add some markers to this map but actually, I don't know if it's free or not and based on checking of pricing of Google MAP products, I found the following Url (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/usage-and-billing) that mentioned that the Google MAP API is for free, so please advise if it's free using it with a marker or I need to pay and in case i used the Iframe instead of MAP API and create my own marker it's free or i need to pay?

Comment: I believe the Embed API is free see https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, you won't be charged for your Google Maps API usage until you turn on auto-billing. The free trial limits you to $300 in credit over 90 days. API users also get $200 of credit per month toward API requests, equal to 100,000 static map requests or around 28,000 dynamic map requests per month.

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing